# Laravel views - passing multiple arrays to a view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Within my Laravel app, I pass a list of jobs to be completed to a view and also send over the number of messages which have been sent about that job:

```
public function index()
{
    $jobs = $this->job->getUsersOwnJobs(Auth::id());

    $jobId = $jobs['id']; // This is an example of what I'm trying to do
    $count = $this->message->model->whereHas('conversation.job',
        function($q) use ($jobId) {
            $q->where('id', $jobId);
        })
    ->count();

    return view('myjobs.index', compact('jobs', 'count'));
}
```

My database is structured so that when a user clicks on a job and sends a message, a row in the conversation table is created which holds the id of the job (my detailed schema can be found here: http://www.laravelsd.com/share/8nBZmc)

The count function should be dependent on the ID of the job, however, how do I pass over the id from the $jobs array, into the $count variable, to load into my views? Should this be using view composers even though they will only appear in one view?

EDIT: Basically I am trying to list all the jobs in a view and display next to them, their respective messages count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what the issue is, but I think you want to count using all the jobs Ids, is that right?

So if that's the case, here is what you need:

```
public function index()
{
    $jobs = $this->job->getUsersOwnJobs(Auth::id());

    $jobsIds = $jobs->lists('id'); // this will give you an array with all the ids of the jobs you want.

    $count = $this->message->model->whereHas('conversation',
        function($q) use ($jobId) {
            $q->whereIn('job_id', $jobsIds);
        })
    ->count();

    return view('myjobs.index', compact('jobs', 'count'));
}
```

Edit:

If all you need is to have the messages count for each job, do this:

Job Model:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Message', 'Conversation');
}
```

So in your view you can call the messages directly:

```
foreach($jobs as $job)
{
    $job->messages()->count();
}
```

or, if you eager loaded the messages relation:

```
foreach($jobs as $job)
{
    $job->messages->count();
}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion to use hasManyThrough on the Job model! Further +1 for providing eager loaded relations as well!